# How to mimic this simple code but for images?

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, matrix

I have the following Python script which represents the input data `X` and the labels `y`:

```
X = np.array([[0,0,1],
            [0,1,1],
            [1,0,1],
            [1,1,1]])

y = np.array([[0],
            [1],
            [1],
            [0]])
```

I would like to do exactly the same but for image data. So, I have a set of images that I know their labels. How can I use the above analogy but for image files? If I would like to keep `y` as-is, how will `X` look like?

Would I need to simply convert my images into vectors for instance?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should to convert the X image into a vector where each pixel in the image is a value. There are countless ways to do this in python, with and without libraries. If you are making X multiple images/batches, you will been to make multiple vectors and/or a Tensor. If you are making a script, I would suggest making the vector axis standard(ex 28x28, etc.), as it makes image-to-vector conversion easier.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you kindly demonstrate that with some example?